# localization UIMenuController ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uimenucontroller

With `UIMenuController` happen something strange. If i run the application in ios7 `UIMenuController` is shown on I need language (Russian).

[image: Good]

If i run it on ios6 - English menu =(

[image: Bad]

**And I need in Russian. Why so?**

P.S. In the setting of the emulator is a Russian language and keyboard.

PP.S. In other apps everything work fine. UIMenuController i nowhere did not changed

Comment: Check in Device not in simulator

Comment: it is problem today find device with ios6. in device with ios7 everything ok

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes i am having same issue. Did you fix this problem?